# Unable to restore the veracrypt volume after quick format

Tags: encryption, formatting, truecrypt, veracrypt, aes

Encrypted 256 GB volume of a 1 TB HDD using VeraCrypt. (standard AES)

Password is known. No rescue disk, keys available.

**Problem:**

My friend formatted the encrypted drive using the quick format and changed the allocation unit size to 32 bit. He now used 5GB of the formatted drive.

**What I did?**

Used multiple recovery programs like Recuva/bitwar/disk drill. They recover only the unencrypted new files in it.

Tried to recover using volume header tool with VeraCrypt. After entering the password, it says

'operation failed due to one or more of the following: -Incorrect password -Incorrect volume PIM number -Incorrect PRF (hash) -Not a valid volume'

I'm 100% sure about my password. There is something else missing

3. Tried TestCrypt too. Didn't work.
4. *Did a quick format to change it to 4096 bits (allocation size) again and ran all the 3 methods above, didn't work.*

I would be immensely grateful if anyone could help me find a solution. There are 220 GB of all my personal/academic files from over 11 years (2011 to 2021). I promise to share the resolution in all forums if I find any, quite stressful.

Any help/suggestion opinion would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you repeat entering the same password 3-4 times? (From VeraCrypt docs: "If the user fails to supply the correct password (and/or keyfiles) twice in a row when trying to mount a volume, VeraCrypt will automatically try to mount the volume using the embedded backup header.")

Comment: Presumable the disk is partitioned. Does the partition start in the same place on the disk?

Comment: Perhaps you should see if there are ways to perform some sort of "raw" AES decryption with the keys on "raw" blocks of the disk / partition (something like piping `dd` output to `openssl dec`, maybe). If you then e.g. `hexdump -C` / `strings` on the decrypted dump and see something sensible (at e.g. somewhere middle of the dump), maybe you then start file / filesystem level rescuing on that. Stop do any more formation on the drive, it's not relevant and won't help.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the question on the VeraCrypt forums.

Comment: Yes, I too read the literature @user1686 but the file system and allocation bit size was also changed by my friend when he quick formatted it. That's the issue here.

Comment: Yes, single volume of 256 gb in a 1tb HDD. it's the entire 256 volume encrypted @ATLief

Comment: Thank you @TomYan but I am not able to do it y myself. Have showed your suggestions to a friend of mine and he is working on a clone of my disk. Will update if it works. Thanks again :-D

Comment: Yes, @harrymc I posted in sourceforge veracrypt forum, no response there. Reddit r/datarecovery and r/veracrypt guys suggested to clone and work on it by using R-studio, ddrescue and a bunch of tools. will update if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data is lost, as even a "quick format" would have destroyed parts of the VeraCrypt header at the very beginning of the volume (due to the new filesystem storing parts of its metadata at the same location).

Your passphrase is not directly used to encrypt the data – it is used to encrypt a randomly-generated master key that is stored in the volume header. So if the volume header is lost, then the entire volume is effectively lost.

VeraCrypt volumes do have an [embedded header backup](https://veracrypt.eu/en/docs/program-menu/#tools-restore-volume-header) at the *end* of the volume – it only gets used if you try to unlock the volume at least 3 times in a row:

> If the user fails to supply the correct password (and/or keyfiles) twice in a row when trying to mount a volume, VeraCrypt will automatically try to mount the volume using the embedded backup header (in addition to trying to mount it using the primary header) each subsequent time that the user attempts to mount the volume

However, there's a chance that either the filesystem initialization (quick-format) or some of the files added by your friend just happened to *also* write over the backup-header area. In that case the data is completely lost.

---

Recovery tools aren't going to work because, well, the entire disk was encrypted – not the individual files, but the actual data blocks, including the old filesystem structures that a recovery tool would be looking for.

Changing the 'allocation unit' size is completely meaningless, as it is not a disk parameter – it is only relevant to the new filesystem that's being created as part of the "formatting", but does not change how the actual disk (or the partition) works.